# How to display all data from three Volley requests once they are all received

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have three request with Volley and I need the data of all three requests to be displayed at the same time. From two requests I receive JSONArrays from each I have to make a Hashmap> from those two and the third request is I have another data set. I have an expandable view with adapter setup. What would be the best way to find out when all data is received and can be proceeded with creating a hashmap and updating the adapter with it??

By the way all data has to be displayed in new Fragment that contains top fragment for the third response data and the bottom fragment with an expandable list view.

I have tried adding everything to the SQLite DB and then displaying everything from it but it doesnt work well for me.

```
public class DBUpdate {

private static DBUpdate dbUpdate = null;
private static String OWMAPIKEY = "&appid=eacc664602550623c7fe93a2732ad127&units=metric";


private DBUpdate() {}


public static DBUpdate getInstance()
{

    if(dbUpdate == null)
    {
        dbUpdate = new DBUpdate();
    }

    return dbUpdate;

}


public boolean updateDaily(String cityId, final Context context){

    String url2 = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=" + cityId + OWMAPIKEY;

    System.out.println("DB daily Test 1");

    JsonObjectRequest jorDaily = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2 ,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {




                    ArrayList<WeatherCondition>  weatherList = new ArrayList<WeatherCondition>();
                    System.out.println("DB daily Test 2");
                    // Trying to extract the imnformation from the JSON response
                    try {
                        JSONObject cityObj = response.getJSONObject("city");
                        JSONObject coordObj = cityObj.getJSONObject("coord");
                        Coordinates coord = new Coordinates(coordObj.getString("lat"),coordObj.getString("lon"));
                        JSONArray list = response.getJSONArray("list");

                        com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City city = new com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City(cityObj.getString("id"),cityObj.getString("name"),cityObj.getString("country"),coord);
                        System.out.println("DB daily Test 3");
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {

                            String date;
                            String time;

                            JSONObject childJSONObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(childJSONObject.getInt("dt") * 1000);

                            date = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/"+ calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":00";

                            JSONObject tempObj = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("temp");
                            JSONObject weatherObj = childJSONObject.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);

                            Wind wind = new Wind(childJSONObject.getString("deg"), childJSONObject.getString("speed"));

                            WeatherCondition w = new WeatherCondition(
                                    weatherObj.getString("icon"),
                                    childJSONObject.getString("humidity")+"%",
                                    "",
                                    weatherObj.getString("description"),
                                    "",
                                    childJSONObject.getString("clouds"),
                                    tempObj.getString("min"),
                                    tempObj.getString("max"),
                                    date,
                                    time,
                                    city,
                                    wind
                            );
                            w.setCurrent("");

                            weatherList.add(w);
                            System.out.println("DB daily Test 4");
                        }

                        DBHelper db = DBHelper.getInstance(context);


                        for (WeatherCondition w: weatherList)
                        {
                            db.insertDaily(w);
                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }





                }
            },


            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("DB daily Test 00000000000000");
                }

            }

    );
    System.out.println("DB daily Test end");
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jorDaily);
    return true;
}

public boolean updateHourly(String cityId, final Context context){
    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + cityId + OWMAPIKEY;
    JsonObjectRequest jorHourly = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {




                    ArrayList<WeatherCondition> weatherList = new ArrayList<WeatherCondition>();

                    // Trying to extract the imnformation from the JSON response
                    try {
                        JSONObject cityObj = response.getJSONObject("city");
                        JSONObject coordObj = cityObj.getJSONObject("coord");
                        Coordinates coord = new Coordinates(coordObj.getString("lat"),coordObj.getString("lon"));
                        JSONArray list = response.getJSONArray("list");

                        com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City city = new com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City(cityObj.getString("id"),cityObj.getString("name"),cityObj.getString("country"),coord);

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {

                            String date;
                            String time;

                            JSONObject childJSONObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(childJSONObject.getInt("dt") * 1000);

                            date = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/"+ calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":00";

                            JSONObject main = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("main");

                            JSONObject windObj = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("wind");
                            JSONObject cloudsObj = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("clouds");
                            JSONObject rainObj = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("rain");



                            try
                            {
                                JSONObject snowObj = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("snow");
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                            }

                            String rain = "";
                            try
                            {
                                rain = rainObj.getString("3h");
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                            }

                            JSONObject weatherObj = childJSONObject.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);

                            Wind wind = new Wind(windObj.getString("deg"),windObj.getString("speed"));

                            WeatherCondition w = new WeatherCondition(
                                    weatherObj.getString("icon"),
                                    main.getString("humidity") + "%",
                                    rain,
                                    weatherObj.getString("description"),
                                    "",
                                    cloudsObj.getString("all"),
                                    main.getString("temp_min"),
                                    main.getString("temp_max"),
                                    date,
                                    time,
                                    city,
                                    wind
                            );

                            weatherList.add(w);
                        }

                        DBHelper db = DBHelper.getInstance(context);


                        for (WeatherCondition w: weatherList)
                        {
                            db.insertHourly(w);
                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            },


            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }

    );
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jorHourly);

    return true;
}

public boolean updateCurrent(final String cityId, final Context context){



    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" + cityId + OWMAPIKEY;
    JsonObjectRequest jorCurrent = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {





                    // Trying to extract the imnformation from the JSON response
                    try {

                        Coordinates coord = new Coordinates(
                                response.getJSONObject("coord").getString("lat"),
                                response.getJSONObject("coord").getString("lon"));

                        com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City city = new com.example.tadas.betterweather4.City(
                                response.getString("id"),
                                response.getString("name"),
                                response.getJSONObject("sys").getString("country"),
                                coord
                        );



                            String date;
                            String time;


                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(response.getInt("dt") * 1000);

                            date = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/"+ calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":00";

                            Wind wind = new Wind(
                                    response.getJSONObject("wind").getString("deg"),
                                    response.getJSONObject("wind").getString("speed")
                            );
                        String rain = "";
                            try{
                                rain = response.getJSONObject("rain").getString("3h")+ "mm";
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {

                            }
                        String snow = "";
                        try{
                            rain = response.getJSONObject("snow").getString("3h");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }

                            WeatherCondition w = new WeatherCondition(
                                    response.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("icon"),
                                    response.getJSONObject("main").getString("humidity") + "%",
                                    rain,
                                    response.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description"),
                                    snow,
                                    response.getJSONObject("clouds").getString("all"),
                                    response.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp_min"),
                                    response.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp_max"),
                                    date,
                                    time,
                                    city,
                                    wind
                            );



                        DBHelper db = DBHelper.getInstance(context);

                        w.setCurrent(response.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp"));

                        db.insertCurrent(w);


                        List<WeatherCondition> list = DBHelper.getInstance(context).getAllDaily(cityId);
                        for(WeatherCondition wd: list)
                        {
                            System.out.println(wd.getMaxTemp());
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            },


            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }

    );
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jorCurrent);

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation like this, I used booleans to track the completions of requests. I used the following process and it worked for me -

1. Initialise booleans isData1Ready = isData2Ready = isData3Ready to
   false;
2. Set the booleans to true when each of the request returns
   with the data
3. Then I wrote a method which checks if all the values
   are true
4. Only when all 3 values are true, you proceed to update the
   UI

Hope this helps!

Comment: very nice!! I like your thinking :) I will try it now

Comment: youre a star! I was breaking my head for couple of days already forgetting the obvious... :)

Comment: Glad it helped!! :D :D

Comment: You're good!! I have another challange :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660972/data-fails-to-be-updated-in-expandable-list

Answer (score 2):

Another way is (especially if your requests are dependent on each other) to make the requests sequential that is, on after the other.

When you receive the response of the first request in your `onResponse()` method then make the second request from there. Then from the `onResponse()` of your second request, make the third request. Finally you can proceed to update your UI when the `onResponse()` of third request is called because you would already know that the first 2 requests have been completed successfully.

Another benefit would be that if any request fails then you can just stop right there without having to make the next requests.

Comment: That is very helpful. thanks very much. I will have to pick the previous answer as it allows me to make no changes if there was an error in receiveving data. I would give you a point for the answer too but my reputation is too low.. eh... :D